# Webpack: output.path, publicPath and chunkFilename selecting concept for projects where html and js files are not in the same folder

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-4, dynamic-loading

From the webpack documentation for `output.publicPath`:

> Simple rule: The URL of your output.path from the view of the HTML
>   page.
>
> ```
> module.exports = { 
>   output: {
>     path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/assets'),
>     publicPath: 'https://cdn.example.com/assets/'   
>   } 
> };
> ```

Above rule is actual for single-page applications, where usually `index.html` and `index.js` are in the  same folder. However, in the projects of multi page websites, usually special folder like `js` or `scripts` is being created. So the file structure of output folder of project could be like:

[image]

I tried a lot of combinations of `output.path` `output.publicPath` and `output.chunkFilename`, however still do not understand, how to correctly select the combination of above parameters to make dynamic load works (e. g. `const MODULE = import('./loadOnDemand/testModule')` which is `chunks/chunk__0.js` in output folder). Please tell me the concept, how to select `output.path` `publicPath` and `chunkFilename`, which will works for above file system, and also could be scaled on below file system:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried webpack magic comments to automatically target the chunk names?
https://medium.com/faceyspacey/how-to-use-webpacks-new-magic-comment-feature-with-react-universal-component-ssr-a38fd3e296a

```
const MODULE = import(/* webpackChunkName: 'test' */'./loadOnDemand/testModule')
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! O'K, it's the solution, and if where are no better solutions, your answer is the best for current Webpack.